# How much data can be sent and received at the same time on a T-3?

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth

A T3 is rated for 45Mbs.

What is the expected run time upload and download speed of a T3 assuming both are happening at the same time?

Comment: So I get two downvotes for what is logically a reasonable question. The downvoters didn't leave a comment on how to improve the question. [I posted this related thread on Meta](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5272/51457)

Comment: The hover text of the downvote icon says `"This question does not show any research effort"`. I'd say this fits the bill. There are two possible options: half-duplex, meaning you'll top out at 45Mbps or full-duplex, meaning you'll top out at 90Mbps. It's trivial to research which of those two categories a T3 falls into on your own.

Comment: @MDMarra I'll take my lumps (in downvotes) and leave this as a signpost for anyone else who needs to ask a simple question like this, and the expected response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T-carrier circuits are full-duplex, so total aggregate theoretical bandwidth would be 90 Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

45Mbps is 45 mega *bits* per second, for an approximate value of *bytes* per second of user data (excluding protocol headers and such) divide by 10, so this would give maximal 4.5 megabytes per second.